# how do call another class in android?

Tags: android, clicklistener

I have a problem. I do not know how to call a different class. the code is for a button (when you click the button a message appears in random) so i thought it would be better if i placed it in a different class as i have also used arrays.Now i do not know how to call the class.

This is my code.I want to call "Firstin" inside SecondActivity.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
private Firstin mFirst = new Firstin ();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        //finds textview

        final Text Ftext = (Text) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        final Text Stext = (Text) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        //finds button view
        Button btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Button btnView2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {




String Answer = mFirst.firstAnswer();

                Ftext.setTextContent(Answer);
            }
        });
```

this is the class I'm trying to call:

```
package com.example.insultgenerator;

import java.util.Random;

public class Firstin {
public String firstAnswer(){
    String [] mResults={
            "its cool",
            "we cool",
            "im cool",
            "he cool",
            "she cool"
            };
    // the button was clicked so replace the answer label with answer
    String Answer = "" ;
    // the two double is a 'empty string 
    Random RandomGen = new Random();// telling the program to construct a random generator
    int RandomNum= RandomGen.nextInt(mResults.length);

    Answer = mResults[RandomNum];
    return(Answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: You can't call a class, unless it is a functor -- but in Java you cannot have that... You mean call *a method* of a class, right? Or what?

Comment: instantiate the class in `onCreate` ! also check your `TextView` casts !

Answer (score 1):

You should cast to  `TextView`

```
        final TextViewFtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        final TextViewStext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

then use TextView.setText(...) method:

```
String Answer = mFirst.firstAnswer();

                Ftext.setText(new Firstin().firstAnswer());
            }
        });
```

then last call the method from the other class with `new Firstin().firstAnswer()` which creates a instance of the class and executes the method.

Comment: short precise .. boom !